# Shuffle content of two json files in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have two json files, `list1.json` and `list2.json` and I managed to concat them, but I have two roles:

Resulting list should contain only 10 random items from `list1.json`, all the items from  `list2.json`, and then I should display them in random order on the page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash for this task.

`_.sampleSize(list1.json, 10)` will give you ten random items,
then `_.concat(_.sampleSize(list1.json, 10), list2.json)` will give you the desired result.

After you have a list containing the desired items, you can randomize its order by using the `_.shuffle` function.

You can read a bit more here:
https://lodash.com/docs#sampleSize and https://lodash.com/docs#concat

Off course both these functions work on JavaScript Arrays and not files, you would have to read/require these files and parse them first.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with plain javascript (but I suggest too going with underscore or lodash as Gilad Artzi says).

```
function array_random_idx(arr) {
    var idx = parseInt(Math.random() * arr.length);
    return idx;
}

function remove_random(arr) {
    var idx = array_random_idx(arr);
    return arr.splice(idx, 1)[0];
}

function array_shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;

    for (i = a.length; i; i -= 1) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        x = a[i - 1];
        a[i - 1] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
}

var result1 = []
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var elem = remove_random(list1.json);
    result1.push(elem);
}

var result = result1.concat(list2.json);
array_shuffle(result);

console.log(result);
```